# TCPDF automatically download a corrupted pdf file instead of showing only in the browser using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, tcpdf

Good day, there is a problem with my TCPDF helper I guest because when I ran my codeigniter project in localhost its work fine, I can view may converted html to pdf in my browser but this time it didn't work in online server

here is my code

View:

```
<?php
tcpdf();
$obj_pdf = new TCPDF('L', PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$obj_pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$title = "JamesLange Survey";
$obj_pdf->SetTitle($title);
$obj_pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, $title, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
$obj_pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$obj_pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$obj_pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont('helvetica');
$obj_pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$obj_pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$obj_pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$obj_pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$obj_pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);
$obj_pdf->setFontSubsetting(false);
$obj_pdf->AddPage();
ob_start();

<h1> This is a body text </h1>

   $content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$obj_pdf->writeHTML($content, true, false, true, false, '');
$obj_pdf->Output('output.pdf','I');
    ?>
```

but the browser want to download the output.pdf instead of view only in the browser.... when I open the downloaded output file, the pdf reader said that my output.pdf file was damage or corrupted file... somebody know this?

Answer (score 0):

please change this line

```
ob_start();
<h1> This is a body text </h1>
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

in to this ;

```
 $content = "<h1> This is a body text </h1>";
```

because you are sending data to headers with ob_ .